# Passing information between textbox and program source code

Tags: c, textbox

So I have myself a project with two files in it, AT.c and main.c (I use DEV-C++).
AT.c contains all the calculation stuff I need, uses command line for I/O and works relatively fine by itself. However, since I need a GUI for the program, I also got the main.c file, which basically creates a window with textboxes for me to put the numbers in.

Anyway, now I'm kinda stuck because I have no idea how to make AT.c read values from those textboxes instead of using the scanf method. I suppose I should probably make some declarations or links between the two codes, but I haven't found anything that could help yet.

The code is main.c is the starting one you get when creating a new windows application project in Dev-C++. I only altered the LRESULTCALLBACK part.

```
#define ID_BUTTON 1
#define ID_TEXTBOX 2

static HWND hwndA;
static HWND hwndB;
/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */


LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
{
    case WM_CREATE:{
         CreateWindow(TEXT("Button"), TEXT("Generate"),
             WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
             10, 160, 80, 20,
             hwnd, (HMENU) ID_BUTTON, NULL, NULL
             );
         hwndA = CreateWindow(TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT(""),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
             190, 130, 70, 15,
             hwnd, (HMENU) ID_TEXTBOX, NULL, NULL
             );    
         hwndB = CreateWindow(TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT(""),
             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
             260, 130, 70, 15,
             hwnd, (HMENU) ID_TEXTBOX, NULL, NULL
             );
         break;
         }
    case WM_COMMAND:{

         if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTON) {
            char wot[256];

            GetWindowText(hwndA, wot, 4);
            SetWindowText(hwndB, wot);
            }
         }

         break;
         }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
        break;
    default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
        return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

return 0;
}
```

The AT.c is just big, yet very simple calculating program.
Like

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h> 

int a, b, c;

main(){
   scanf("%d", &a);
   scanf("%d", &b);
   printf("\n%d", a+b);
   system("pause");
}
```

just with bunch of ifs and loops.

Comment: Please provide some code. What do you have so far?

Comment: @pyStarter
Uploaded some code, maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have added both `AT.C` and `MAIN.C` to your project. You can easily communicate, it doesn't matter that they are written in different files, unless I didn't understand the question.

In file1.C:

```
#include "headers.h"
//..
char Input_Text[256]; 
void Function_in_file1(const char *buf)
{
   //..
}
//..
```

In file2.C:

```
#include "headers.h"
//..
extern char Input_Text[256]; 
void Function_in_file1(const char *buf);//let the compiler know this is a valid function and you wrote it somewhere else
//...
case WM_COMMAND:{
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == ID_BUTTON) {
        char temp[50];
        GetWindowText(hwndA, temp, 4);
        Function_in_file1(temp); //call Function_in_file1() in file1.C
        //or
        GetWindowText(hwndA, Input_Text, 4);//Input_Text is available in file1.C
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, I'm still not getting it to work properly, but that is probably because I don't have much experience in messing with buffers.

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't mixed up the code names? Because the code you suggest for AT.C seems like it would fit really well in main.c, with the button command and window manipulation and all. Or do I need to declare that button pressed case in my calculation code as well?

Also, forgive for a noob question, but what should I write in the foo function? Could you give an example, or, better yet, suggest where I could find a simplistic example program for this?

Comment: I don't know which file is which, I renamed it file1.c & file2.c. The order of the file number is not important. You can call the function in file1 from file2. If you are getting an error then write it here.

Comment: Well, I tried this code configuration, but it gives me:
[Linker error] undefined reference to `InfoHut'

Comment: I don't know what is InfoHut.

Comment: That's what I named the function